# Reverse engineering statistics

Tags: statistics

Say we had a data set of exam scores and we don't know each persons individual test score, but we did know the average, standard deviation, and the number of individuals that took the exam. Could we "reverse engineer" the data we do have to find each individuals score?

Comment: No, we could not

Comment: You could simulate exams by taking that many independent samples from a normal distribution with that mean and variance. This wouldn't tell you what the true exam was like, but could be useful depending on what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. As soon as you have at least $n=3$ individuals, you can find lists of numbers possessing the same mean and standard deviation. For example, the lists $1,2,6$ and $0,4,5$. The problem is that you have only two constraints on $n$ variables. When $n=2$, you can solve uniquely; for larger $n$ you may not be lucky enough to find a unique solution.